# Work out time 1.5 hours ahead using current time and display this in the list

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I have the following code someone presses on the Table and its displays the current time which is the arrival time of a customer.

I want to display the time they must leave by, next to the current time this will always be 1.5 hours ahead I can not work out how to do this. everything I have tried comes back with an error.

Still new to Xcode

any help would be great

```
    import SwiftUI

struct TimeListView: View {
    
    @State var tableOne = false
    @State var tableTwo = false
    @State var tableThree = false
    
    
    var body: some View {
        // Title
        
        VStack {
            Text("Arrival Times")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            
            // List View
            List {
                
                // Table 1
                HStack {
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.tableOne.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Table 1 -")
                    })
                    if tableOne {
                        Text(getCurrentTime())
                    }
                }
                
                // Table 2
                HStack {
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.tableTwo.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Table 2 -")
                    })
                    if tableTwo {
                        Text(getCurrentTime())
                    }
                }
                // Table 3
                HStack {
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.tableThree.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Table 3 -")
                    })
                    if tableThree {
                        Text(getCurrentTime())
                    }
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}

struct TimeListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TimeListView()
    }
}

// Get Current Time Function

func getCurrentTime() -> String {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_UK_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    
    return dateFormatter.string(from: Date())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need make a date and add 1.5 hour to it, also you forgot create 3 deferent State for them.

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        TimeListView()
    }
}
```

---

```
struct TimeListView: View {
    
    @State private var table1: Bool = false
    @State private var table2: Bool = false
    @State private var table3: Bool = false

    @State private var timeForShow1: String?
    @State private var timeForShow2: String?
    @State private var timeForShow3: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack {
            
            Text("Arrival Times")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            
            List {
                
                HStack {
                    
                    Text("Table 1 -")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            
                            if table1 { table1.toggle() }
                            else { timeForShow1 = getCurrentTime; table1.toggle() }
                            
                        }
                    
                    if table1 { Text(timeForShow1 ?? "not available!") }
                    
                }
                
                
                HStack {
                    
                    Text("Table 2 -")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            
                            if table2 { table2.toggle() }
                            else { timeForShow2 = getCurrentTime; table2.toggle() }
                            
                        }
                    
                    if table2 { Text(timeForShow2 ?? "not available!") }
                    
                }
                
                
                
                HStack {
                    
                    Text("Table 3 -")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            
                            if table3 { table3.toggle() }
                            else { timeForShow3 = getCurrentTime; table3.toggle() }
                            
                        }
                    
                    if table3 { Text(timeForShow3 ?? "not available!") }
                    
                }
                
                
                
                
            }
            
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

---

```
var getCurrentTime: String? {
    
    if let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 90, to: Date()) {
        
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_UK_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        
    }
    else {
        
        return nil
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Amazing thank you works just how I wanted

Comment: @TimJMcGrath: I did my best, I just refactored 5 time my codes, and I can not find anything to improve, I would say the code that we are seeing is best possible I think, and thank you for this good question, I enjoyed solving issue.

Comment: I have 16 tables but soon as I add 10 I get an error I have tried to group them but maybe I am adding the group in the wrong place

Comment: please make a new question, I come to that new question and work together there. we cannot work more than one question here, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably get a half dozen different ways of doing this but this version allows for adaptive/reusable code. You can easily add a Table by adding one to the `var tables: [Table]` everything would adjust automatically.

```
import SwiftUI
class Table: ObservableObject {
    let id: UUID = UUID()
    @Published var name: String
    @Published var status: Bool
    @Published var entryTime: Date
    var exitTime: Date{
        return entryTime.addingTimeInterval(60*60*1.5)
    }
    init(name: String, status: Bool = false, entryTime: Date = Date.init(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)) {
        self.name = name
        self.status = status
        self.entryTime = entryTime
    }
}
struct TimeListView: View {
    
    @State var tables: [Table] = [Table(name: "Table 1 -"), Table(name: "Table 2 -"), Table(name: "Table 3 -")]
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Arrival Times")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            List {
                ForEach(tables, id: \.id, content: { table in
                    TableView(table: table)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
struct TableView: View {
    @ObservedObject var table: Table
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                table.status.toggle()
                table.entryTime = Date()
            }, label: {
                Text(table.name)
            })
            if table.status{
                Text(table.entryTime, formatter: dateFormatter)
                Text(table.exitTime, formatter: dateFormatter)
            }
        }
    }
}
struct TimeListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TimeListView()
    }
}
var dateFormatter: DateFormatter {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_UK_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
    
    return dateFormatter
}
```