# Having trouble adding a foreach loop as there is 3 @State Values used

Tags: swiftui

I have a list of tables which displays when clicked a time and also set a notification.

I currently have the code 20 times which is not a great option. I have tired adding it to a for each loop but not sure how to do this for the @state part

```
 // MARK: Start Table 7
                    HStack {
                        
                        Text("Table 7 -")
                            .onTapGesture {
                                // Notification Table 1
                                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                                content.title = "Table 7 - 10 min Notice"
                                content.subtitle = "Please ask Customer to Leave"
                                content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

                                // show this notification five seconds from now
                                let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 4800, repeats: false)

                                // choose a random identifier
                                let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "t7not", content: content, trigger: trigger)

                                // add our notification request
                                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
                                // Notification End
                                timeForShow7 = getCurrentTime
                                table7.toggle()
                                ttable7.toggle()
                            }
                        
                        
                        if table7 { Image(systemName: "clock") ; Text(timeForShow7 ?? "not available!") }
                        
                        // Clear Table Code
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            
                            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                            
                            center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: ["t7not"])
                            table7.toggle()
                            ttable7.toggle()
                            
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Table Clear 7")
                        }).padding(5).background(Color.red).cornerRadius(5.0)
                        
                    }
                    
                    // end Table 7
```

Comment: Your question is about dealing with 3 `@State` variables, but you don't show any definitions of `@State` variables at all -- can you modify your code to show all of the relevant information?

Comment: The answer I gave you in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66711812/work-out-time-1-5-hours-ahead-using-current-time-and-display-this-in-the-list) question detailed that

Comment: Thank you lorem ipsum I didn’t see that other reply it worked. Great